# Steam Market: language json response

Tags: json, google-play, steam

If I open this link in my browser, I see the **Spanish texts** and **coins Euro**: http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?l=espanish&cc=es&country=ES&start=0&count=20&currency=3&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=tag_weapon_awp&appid=730&query=Man-o%27-war

But the following code, I always throw coins in $USD and texts in English:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?l=espanish&cc=es&country=ES&start=0&count=20&currency=3&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=tag_weapon_awp&appid=730&query=Man-o%27-war";
    $json_object= file_get_contents($url);
    $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

    preg_match_all('/<span style="color:white">(.*)<\/span>/',$json_decoded->results_html, $sor);

    foreach($sor[1] as $k => $v)
    {
        echo $v."<br/>";
    }
```

The code print:

```
$34.53 USD
$31.92 USD
$115.00 USD
$102.01 USD
```

What I can do to get euros??

Comment: It seems as though this is a bug. Obviously Steam Support isn't the quickest at responding, but they are most likely the only ones who can fix it. In the mean time, I suggest converting the dollars to euros using the equation `euro = dollar * 0.89`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Send a message to support VALVE, but I'm still waiting for your reply.
I prefer to show price in Dollars which do the conversion to Euros using a function.
* 0.89 is a value that can change, and do not want to depend on manual updates to the web.

Comment: There must be an API out there for currency conversions. I'll tell you if I came across one.